# ENOENT: no such file or directory in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've started learning Gatsby, every time I make any changes in `src/pages` folder, it gives an error that comes from `.cache` folder like this:
Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...\Gatsby\src\pages\someFile.js'
```

I am deleting `.cache` folder then re-running `gatsby develop` command and it works, but it takes more time.

Question: Is there any command to make it faster or easier?

Answer (score 3):

> Question: Is there any command to make it faster or easier?

`gatsby clean` does the trick. It removes the `.cache` and the `/public` folders. From [Gatsby's docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/#clean):

> At the root of a Gatsby site, wipe out the cache (`.cache` folder) and
> public directories:
>
> `gatsby clean`
>
> This is useful as a last resort when your local project seems to have
> issues or content does not seem to be refreshing. Issues this may fix
> commonly include:
>
> - Stale data, e.g. this file/resource/etc. isn’t appearing GraphQL
>   error, e.g. this
> - GraphQL resource should be present but is not
> - Dependency issues, e.g. invalid version, cryptic errors in console,
>   etc.
> - Plugin issues, e.g. developing a local plugin and changes don’t
>   seem to be taking effect

I personally add my own commands in the `package.json`, like:

```
  "scripts": {
    // other scripts
    "start": "gatsby clean && gatsby develop",
  },
```

So every time I need to run a `gatsby develop` I run `yarn start` or `npm run start` instead, executing the `gatsby clean` command before.